# Backtesting a 'once per bar' security strategy without the 1 bar delay?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

After reading through [security() revisited [PineCoders]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/00jFIl5w-security-revisited-PineCoders/) and [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) several times I still had some questions on how to properly combine security function tuple data with data from the current chart and timeframe.

I was referred by PineCoders in Trading View chat to a more experienced and published dev who encouraged me to use the following function when working with tuples and the security function, and the following method to work with the output:

```
f_secWrapper2Tuple( _symbol, _resolution, _data1, _data2 ) =>
          security( _symbol, _resolution,
          [ _data1[1], _data2[1] ], 
          lookahead = true )
```

1. Call functions normally to get 'raw' data (e.g, a basic RSI call,
   with no delay)
2. Pass the raw data into the security function as is, allowing the security function to
   apply the one bar delay
3. Before plotting or using the non-security 'raw' data from the current chart and timeframe to determine a buy signal, apply a 1 bar delay but do not apply a delay to data from security as that has already been applied by the function.
4. As the previous bar data used for the buy condition will never repaint, use *once per bar* to generate alerts (on bar open), not *once per bar close*.

The 1 bar delay is always applied to the raw data, whether or not it is combined with data from the security function to form a buy signal. This works well for generating alerts from study scripts, and there is zero delay when taking data from higher timeframes. By this I mean that if the chart running the script is a 1 hour (Lower Time Frame) and it combines some data from that chart with data from a daily chart (Higher Time Frame), as soon as the condition is found true on the HTF (at the open of the current daily bar checking the previous bar as we use the 1 bar delay) it is also true immediately on the LTF at 00:00. There is no delay of a bar before this happens, at least in the study version - which I have observed in some other scripts.

This works very well for generating alerts from study scripts, as soon as a bar opens where the condition is found true the alert fires. In this screenshot the condition that controls whether the background changes from red to green is the same condition the buy alert uses, here firing on the open of the bar August 30th at 18:00:

[image: Study script]

Unfortunately, when I try to backtest this in a strategy script there is a 1 LTF bar delay penalty incurred so that the same buy does not occur until an hour later at 19:00:

[image: Strategy script]

On testing just current timeframe signals (no security calls) against another script that does not access data from the previous bar and is intended to generate alerts *once per bar close* I observe the 1 bar delay changes reported netprofit from 01/01/2020 from ~3000% to ~%2000.

I read warnings about not using *calc_on_every_tick* and *calc_on_order_fills* but despite this I tried them and they did not resolve the issue.

Is there an error in how I am trying to backtest, or if not is there some workaround I can use so that the buy orders will occur on open of the correct bars when backtesting? Perhaps for backtesting I can remove the 1 bar delay from security and current timeframe and chart data, or use some other security function, and rely on the performance results generated to represent the performance I could expect from the study version (with the 1 bar delay applied and using once per bar alerts) operating in realtime? I read that lookahead can cause some issue backtesting so even if the way I am using security for the study script is correct, is it also correct for backtesting a strategy?

EDIT:

This code is a basic example of how I am using security, which works well for study scripts but causes 1 bar delay in strategy scripts, even when not using the 1 bar delay/offset on the realtime 'raw' data. I hope that this will better demonstrate the issue and what I am trying to achieve.

Study version:

```
//@version=4
study( "SMA Security Demo (study)", overlay = true )

i_useSecurity = input ( true, "Use security", type = input.bool )
i_symbol = input( title="Symbol", type = input.symbol, defval = "")
i_resolution = input( title="Resolution", type = input.resolution, defval = "" )

// 1 is what I use for study scripts to send alerts on once per bar (open)
i_realtimeOffset = input( title = "Reatime Offset", defval = 1 , options = [ 1, 0 ] )
// 1 is what I use as 0 means using repainting realtime bar data and I am not trying to do this
i_securityOffset = input( title = "Reatime Offset", defval = 1 , options = [ 1, 0 ] )

f_secWrapper( _symbol, _resolution, _data1 ) =>
          security( _symbol, _resolution,
          _data1[i_securityOffset], 
          lookahead = true )

sma50Raw = sma( close, 50 )
sma100Raw = sma( close, 100 )

smaBuyRaw = sma50Raw > sma100Raw

smaBuySec = f_secWrapper( syminfo.tickerid, "240", smaBuyRaw )

buy = smaBuyRaw[i_realtimeOffset] and ( i_useSecurity ? smaBuySec : true )

plot( sma50Raw, color = color.yellow )
plot( sma100Raw, color = color.blue )

bgcolor( buy ? color.green : color.red )
```

Below is the same study script loading in the upper chart on the 1H, which generates a buy signals on the bar after yellow SMA50 is greater than blue SMA100 on that timeframe, but also as I have it set to *use security* also confirms the same condition on the 4H chart before firing the buy signal. This is with the realtime offset set to 1 as I have been using it. The background colour change from red to green is indicative of the buy signal and as we are always referencing the previous bar, there is no repainting risk in taking the signal on the open of the current bar, and generating alerts with *once per bar* instead of *once per bar close*. For reference I have the script set on the lower 4H chart to just change background when just the the condition is occurring on that particular chart.

[image: Study version, dual chart]

Observe above that there is no delay when accessing HTF data from the 4H. When both the new 1H and 4H bars open at 18:00 UTC, the condition is found true on each at the same time for the first time (since the last sell signal). This is because on the 1H although the 50SMA was already greater than the 100SMA and is still on the previous bar, on the 4h the previous bar has just closed with the same condition met after a period of it not being met.

What I am trying to achieve, is to backtest this using a strategy, but as below, there is a one bar delay when doing so with the same code:

[image: Strategy version, dual chart]

Strategy version:

```
//@version=4
strategy("SMA Security Demo (strategy)", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

i_useSecurity = input ( true, "Use security", type = input.bool )
i_symbol = input( title="Symbol", type = input.symbol, defval = "")
i_resolution = input( title="Resolution", type = input.resolution, defval = "" )

// 1 is what I use for study scripts to send alerts on once per bar (open)
i_realtimeOffset = input( title = "Reatime Offset", defval = 1 , options = [ 1, 0 ] )
// 1 is what I use as 0 means using repainting realtime bar data and I am not trying to do this
i_securityOffset = input( title = "Security Offset", defval = 1 , options = [ 1, 0 ] )

f_secWrapper( _symbol, _resolution, _data1 ) =>
          security( _symbol, _resolution,
          _data1[i_securityOffset], 
          lookahead = true )

sma50Raw = sma( close, 50 )
sma100Raw = sma( close, 100 )

smaBuyRaw = sma50Raw > sma100Raw 

smaBuySec = f_secWrapper( i_symbol, i_resolution, smaBuyRaw )

buy = smaBuyRaw[i_realtimeOffset] and ( i_useSecurity ? smaBuySec : true )

plot( sma50Raw, color = color.yellow )
plot( sma100Raw, color = color.blue )

bgcolor( buy ? color.new( color.lime, 75 ) : color.new( color.red, 75) )

if buy
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long )
else
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short )
```

As removing the offset was suggested I included an option for this in the code, I assume just for the realtime data rather than the security function but I have also included an offset option for that also - even though that means using data that is repainting which I do not want to do.

Setting the realtime offset to 0 does not change the location of the buy order in the strategy and it still occurs at 18:00 UTC as in the screenshot above.

Below with the security offset to 0, which as this means using repainting data the condition is determined true 4 hours earlier at 08:00, though even at this the strategy is still late to pick it up and it does not place the order until the next bar!

[image: Strategy version, dual chart]

I hope this makes more clear the issue I am trying to resolve. I expect there is an error in how I am using security, perhaps the solution is that I can still use non-repainting zero-delay HTF data on a study but with a different security function (that also works with tuples), that does not requie me to apply a delay to LTF/current chart data to work with, and that will allow me to use *once per bar close* alerts and backtest properly?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand from your post, you're trying to enter trades as soon as you get the signals, when the bar have not closed yet and is still forming/repainting. If you've been in the trading industry enough, this is not advisable, people will usually wait for the bar to close to "confirm" the signal.

To answer your question is it possible to backtest without 1 bar delay. The answer is no, atleast not on historical bars. If you set `calc_on_every_tick` to `true`, you will achieve the effect that you're looking for, but only for present and future bars.

Edit:

Not referencing previous bars on the strategy script should fix it.
[image]

Blue bgcolor represents `smaCrossover[1]` in a study script.

Green bgcolor represents `smaCrossover` in a strategy script.

That should get you the result that you're looking for, which I assume is entering at the open at 18:00.

**Edit 2:**

My last attempt at this, I'm still unsure of what exactly you're looking for but I hope these scripts help. Since I can't have multiple charts like yours on tradingview, I just made two scripts, one for 1h and one for 4h. They both enter at 26 July '21 12:00 on 1 hour and 4 hour chart. Both scripts also check if 50 sma is greater than 100 sma for both 1 hour and 4 hour chart.

*For the 1 hour chart:*

```
//@version=4
strategy("1h main", overlay=true)

condition1 = sma(close, 50) > sma(close, 100)

sma50FourHour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", sma(close, 50))
sma100FourHour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", sma(close, 100))
condition2 = sma50FourHour > sma100FourHour

longCondition = condition1 and condition2

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

bgcolor(longCondition ? color.new(color.lime, 75) : color.new(color.red, 75))
plot(sma(close, 100))
plot(sma(close, 50), color=color.yellow)




atr14 = atr(14)
float longEntry = na
float longSL = na
float longTP = na
longEntry := longCondition ? close : longEntry[1]
longSL := longCondition ? close - atr14*5 : longSL[1]
longTP := longCondition ? close + atr14*5 : longTP[1]
strategy.exit("tp or sl", "long", limit=longTP, stop=longSL)
```

[image]

*For the 4 hour chart:*

```
//@version=4
strategy("4h main", overlay=true)

condition1 = sma(close, 50) > sma(close, 100)

sma50OneHour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", sma(close, 50))
sma100OneHour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", sma(close, 100))
condition2 = sma50OneHour > sma100OneHour

longCondition = condition1 and condition2

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

bgcolor(longCondition ? color.new(color.lime, 75) : color.new(color.red, 75))
plot(sma(close, 100))
plot(sma(close, 50), color=color.yellow)




atr14 = atr(14)
float longEntry = na
float longSL = na
float longTP = na
longEntry := longCondition ? close : longEntry[1]
longSL := longCondition ? close - atr14*5 : longSL[1]
longTP := longCondition ? close + atr14*5 : longTP[1]
strategy.exit("tp or sl", "long", limit=longTP, stop=longSL)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the general advice is to use once per bar close but as I understand it this is because the real time bar repaints. In my script, although the real time bar does repaint, I am never actually using repainting data from the realtime bar, I am always referencing the bar previous to create the buy signal, (e.g buy = rsiRawBuy[1] and rsiSecurityBuy ) and as such I am not using data that is still forming/repainting. Alerts that occur on the open of the current bar (even though referencing the previous bar), occur in 24h markets at the same time as using the close of the previous bar.

Comment: You don't need to use buySignal[1] to limit signals to only fire at bar's close in a strategy script since by default it already does that. You can try not referencing previous bar. Everything should work unless you're actually using repaiting data.

Comment: Edited my post as well.

Comment: Thanks brokeboynomore I thought that might resolve this but unfortunately once you add in the security function it does not work. I have edited my post to include code for an example study and strategy, and screenshots demonstrating the issue which I hope better explains the issue and also why just removing the offset does not work.